# Empty char variable

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c, sketch

How do I empty all the values inside a variable `char array[256];`?

I tried a for loop assigning an empty value at each iteration, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please post this loop.

Comment: You can't "empty" an array, you can only fill it with meaningless values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char array[256];

...

int i;
for( i=0; i<256;i++ ) {
    array[i] = 0x00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a single-line command you can use:

```
memset(array, 0, 256);
```

Comment: Or `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);` preferably.

Comment: @NickGammon Assuming you are using "array" directly, and not in a function which has a pointer passed to it.  Better is to use a `#define` or a `const int` for both the array size and the memset length.

Comment: Quite right, for a pointer that is correct.